# Accumulated Backlog in DAX (recursive function)

Tags: recursion, powerbi, dax

I want to calculate the accumulated Backlog based on demand and capacity in DAX. In excel this is very easy as you can select the result of the previous row. The backlog cannot go below zero.

DAX doesn't allow recursive formula's or circular dependencies. So how can I write a **measure** that yields the "backlog" variable based on Demand & Capacity? Any ideas?

Example with solution "backlog"

```
Table = 


DATATABLE (
    "Index", INTEGER,
    "Month", STRING,
    "DEMAND", INTEGER,
    "Capacity", INTEGER,
    "Backlog", INTEGER,
    {
        {1, "SEP", 1000, 900, 100},
        {2, "OCT", 1000, 900, 200},
        {3, "NOV", 1000, 1100, 100},
        {4, "DEC", 1000, 1200, 0},
        {5, "JAN", 1000, 900, 100},
        {6, "FEB", 1000, 1100, 0},
        {7, "MAR", 1000, 1100, 0},
        {8, "APR", 1000, 1100, 0}
    }
)
```

Measures depending on other measures referencing the result of previous month will give circular dependencies.

Comment: What is your expected output ? I can't understand this part "can I write a measure that yields the "backlog" variable based on Demand & Capacit"

Comment: The expected output is the "backlog" column provided in the example, calculated by the difference between demand & capacity. It should accumulate month over month & can not go under zero.